# Are if and else if statements bugged in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm fairly new to GAS and Javascript in general and have searched far and wide to find an answer to why this isn't working, but haven't found a solution. I was wondering if one of you guys could find the problem. Here's my code:

```
function maintenanceRequest() {


var findFirstRequest = GmailApp.search("to:censored label:ems-request AND is:unread", 0, 1)[0];
  var firstRequest = findFirstRequest.getMessages()[0];
  var parseRequest = firstRequest.getPlainBody();
  var requestString = String(parseRequest);

  if ("Mark archived mail as read" == requestString) {
    markArchivedAsRead();
    findFirstRequest.moveToArchive();
  }
  else if ("Cleanup" == requestString) {
    weeklyCleanup();
    findFirstRequest.moveToArchive();
  }
  else {
    GmailApp.sendEmail("censored", "Failure to parse command", "The EMS has recieved your request but has failed to recognize the command '" + parseRequest + "'. Please try again, using the terms 'Mark archived as read' or 'Cleanup'. If you would like to add an eligible command, please refer to function 'maintenanceRequest'.", {
      name: "Email Maintenance Service",
      from: "censored"
    })
    //Add moveToArchive line here after debugging
  }
}
```

The code always skips the `if` and `else if` statements and jumps to the `else` statement, regardless of the email's content. I've tried using both `==` and `===` to no avail, and have tried switching the sides that the arguments are on. To no avail. I even created a new `var`, `requestString` to convert `parseRequest` to a string, even though I'm like 99% certain that it already is a string.. so what gives? Where's the problem?

Comment: Have you logged the request string and ensured that it is actually returning what you think it should be in terms of both case sensitivity and length (could have extra whitespace on the end)?

Comment: `requestString` doesn't equal what you're comparing it to? Are you instead trying to see if `requestString` *contains* the strings in question?

Comment: put a `console.log(requestString)` right after you declare the requestString, to see that in fact the value of it is "Mark archived mail as read" or "Cleanup".

Comment: The log service for server side Apps Script is `Logger.log()`.  `Logger.log('requestString: ' + requestString);`  Then under the VIEW menu, choose LOGS.  You might want to use the JavaScript `indexOf()` method to check for the existence of that string inside of the email content instead of looking for an exact match.  I'm assuming that as long as the string "Mark archived mail as read" exists in the email, that you want to have something done, regardless of what other content might be in the email.

Comment: @tanenbring So I did Logger.log(parseRequest.length); Logger.log(requestString.length); and they both return 9 characters even though it should be 7 (I was trying Cleanup). No whitespace in the email so I have no idea...

Comment: @SandyGood yes I've been using Logger.log throughout my testing, thanks for the info. I'd rather test for that term exclusively however..

Comment: Try adding trim to the string: `requestString = requestString.trim()`

Comment: @manonthemat I used Logger.log instead since we're using GAS, and it did in fact return the correct value (even though the else statement is still running...)

Comment: @tanenbring oh my god it worked! Thanks so much. I guess Inbox must've added the whitespace itself because I'm positive that I didn't haha.

Comment: Glad it worked. Yeah, it's usually a safe bet to use trim on any string you're getting from another service.

Comment: @tanenbring  You should add your suggestion as an answer.  I know it's a simple, easy fix, but it did answer the question.  Otherwise, this question may be unanswered forever.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding trim to the string: `requestString = requestString.trim()`

It's usually a safe bet to use trim on any string you're getting from another service.